get post attachments of a specific post
I was using this before and it was working , but now the issue raised in it. I want to pick attached audios of a post. it is fetching old audios attached and not showing new attachments,
below is the function select_audios I call this and it is returing audios.
function select_audios()
{
    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    $args = $_REQUEST;

    $cat_id = isset($args["cat_id"]) ? $args["cat_id"] : "";

    $page_number = isset($args["paged"]) ? $args["paged"] : "";
    $page_size = isset($args["page_size"]) ? $args["page_size"] : "";

    $orderby = isset($args["orderby"]) ? $args["orderby"] : "";
    $order = isset($args["order"]) ? $args["order"] : "";

    $categories = get_categories();
 


    $args = [
        "post_type" =>  "post",
        "paged" => $page_number,
        "posts_per_page" => $page_size,
        "tax_query" => [
            [
                "taxonomy" => "category",
                "field" => "term_id",
                "terms" =>  $cat_id,
            ],
        ],
        "orderby" => $orderby,
        "meta_key" => "order",
        "order" => $order,
    ];
    
    $audios_list = process_audio_items($args); 
 

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $out = json_encode($audios_list);

    unset($audios_list);

    die($out);
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_select_audios", "select_audios");
add_action("wp_ajax_select_audios", "select_audios");

The second function is called by parent function it fetches the attached audios based on the ID
function process_audio_items($args) {
    

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $audios_list = [];

    if ($loop->have_posts()):
        while ($loop->have_posts()):
            $loop->the_post();

            $audio_item = (object) [];
 

            $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
            $audio_item->{'audio_img_url'} = $img_url;
            $site_dir = get_site_url(null, "", null);
            if (empty($img_url)) {
                $audio_item->{'audio_img_url'} =
                    $site_dir .
                    "/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-512x512-Google-Android-Chrome-8-1.png";
            }
              $audio = get_posts([
                "post_parent" => get_the_ID(),
                "post_type" => "attachment",
                "post_mime_type" => "audio",
            ]);
            $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

            $audio_item->{'id'} = htmlspecialchars($audio[0]->ID);
            $audio_item->{'title'} = htmlspecialchars(get_the_title());
            $audio_item->{'ordernumber'} = $meta["order"][0];
            $audio_item->{'audio_post'} = get_home_url();
            $audio_item->{'description'} = htmlspecialchars(get_the_excerpt());
            $audio_item->{'audio_src'} = wp_get_attachment_url(
                $audio[0]->ID,
                "full"
            );
            array_push($audios_list, $audio_item);

            unset($audio_item);
        endwhile;
    endif;
 
    return $audios_list;
}

